# Spyder failing to launch - “could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows”

Tags: python-3.x, installation, anaconda, spyder, qtplugin

I've recently had to do a fresh install of windows and reinstall all the software I was previously using including anaconda.

I still have all the data from before the reinstall. To save me from pip installing all the packages I was using, I thought it would be easier to copy and paste the environment info from pre windows reinstall (left image) into the environment folder of the freshly installed anaconda (right).([Information/Folders in question)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JByj.jpg)

[I'm getting this error message when I try to launch Spyder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCary.jpg)
Juypter notebook seems to be working fine but I get the error shown when I attempt to launch Sypder in the 'imported environment' TensorFlow1.8CPU.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this?

I'm also open to hear any other ways of importing the environment from pre windows install anaconda folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing spyder with a lower version.

Comment: Please edit your answer to mention what version of Spyder worked for you.